# How to run a project Caffe with CPU only

Tags: tensorflow

i'm using `Ubuntu 14.04` without GPU and i want to run this code ( `with CPU only` ). I want to run this code with CPU ( not with GPU)  : https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF . what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The Github repository you are referring to is a **TensorFlow** implementation of Faster-RCNN, not **Caffe**.

If you want to use the **Caffe** implementation, you have to use this repository : https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn

You have to edit the Python scripts that are used to train and test the model, e.g. `train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py` so that the line `caffe.set_mode_gpu()` is replaced by `caffe.set_mode_cpu()`. You might have to compile **Caffe** by editing the `Makefile.config` file to remove CUDNN and CUDA support.

Note that Caffe on CPU will be **very slow** compared to GPU computing.